# split white spaces using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have this line of code to split the white spaces in a text file:

```
my @line_splits = split /\s+/, $ine;
```

And this is the few contents of the text file:

```
  1 2016-09-27 14:07:20.084877
  2 2016-09-27 14:07:20.084998
  3 2016-09-27 14:07:20.131343
  4 2016-09-27 14:07:20.131374
  6 2016-09-27 14:07:20.137359
  7 2016-09-27 14:07:20.137556
  8 2016-09-27 14:07:20.137796
  9 2016-09-27 14:07:20.437769
 10 2016-09-27 14:07:20.437796
100 2016-09-27 14:07:23.293661
```

My goal is to get the date and the time (which I knew is on $line_splits[1] and $line_splits[2]).

But when I ran my perl script, the lines from 1 to 99 are wrong while on the 100th and up I've got what I've want.

```
Time Stamp: 98 2016-09-27               --> line 98
Time Stamp: 99 2016-09-27               --> line 99
Time Stamp: 2016-09-27 14:07:23.293661  --> line 100
Time Stamp: 2016-09-27 14:07:23.299406  --> line 101
Time Stamp: 2016-09-27 14:07:23.299437  --> line 102
```

Can someone tell me if what is wrong with the regex or there is another way to do this?

I don't know if it is already duplicated in here but any help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: Skip the leading spaces with `/^\s+(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+/`

Comment: `$line =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//` trims whitespace from the left and right of a line. I use it a lot, saves from a lot of bugs.

Comment: You don't need to skip the leading whitespace at all, as that's default behaviour if you just `split ' '` instead of `split /\s+/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow, lots of complicated answers, but the solution's really easy.

Just use `split` without the `/\s+/` regex.

The [default behaviour](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) - or what you get if you specify just `' '` to split - is that it ignores leading whitespace. But with `/\s+/` it doesn't.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  chomp;
  my @fields  = split;
  print $fields[2],"\n"
}

__DATA__
  1 2016-09-27 14:07:20.084877
  2 2016-09-27 14:07:20.084998
  3 2016-09-27 14:07:20.131343
  4 2016-09-27 14:07:20.131374
  6 2016-09-27 14:07:20.137359
  7 2016-09-27 14:07:20.137556
  8 2016-09-27 14:07:20.137796
  9 2016-09-27 14:07:20.437769
 10 2016-09-27 14:07:20.437796
100 2016-09-27 14:07:23.293661
```

Comment: Gah. This is, of course, the best answer. I knew there was a better solution, but in my under-caffeinated state I just couldn't pull it out of my head.

Comment: But what would happen if the OP had multiple spaces between each field?  Would the default split be able to handle this?

Comment: Yes. By default split is 'any whitespace' omitting any leading. This is so because it's the same behaviour as `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Trim whitespace from the left of each line before splitting by space:

```
$line =~ s/^\s+//;
my @line_splits = split /\s+/, $line;
```

As usual, @Wiktor chimed in with this option which will retain the whitespace preceding numbers less than 100:

```
my @line_splits = split /^\s+(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+/, $line;
```

And in Perl 6 there will be a true `trim` function:

```
$line .= trim;
my @line_splits = split /\s+/, $line;
```

Comment: Sadly I don't have enough reputation in here.

Comment: This approach actually removes the leading whitespace, while `/^\s+(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+/` will keep them. Just choose whichever you need.

Comment: Thanks @Tim and Wiktor, both are working but for now I will use Tim's answer. Sure your (Wiktor) suggestion is correct and it also helps me gain another knowledge since I'm new at using perl :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a regex to extract the bits of the string that you're interested in (i.e. all the non-whitespace bits).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<DATA>) {
  my @line_splits = /(\S+)/g;
  say "Time Stamp: $line_splits[1] $line_splits[2]";
}

__DATA__
  1 2016-09-27 14:07:20.084877
  2 2016-09-27 14:07:20.084998
  3 2016-09-27 14:07:20.131343
  4 2016-09-27 14:07:20.131374
  6 2016-09-27 14:07:20.137359
  7 2016-09-27 14:07:20.137556
  8 2016-09-27 14:07:20.137796
  9 2016-09-27 14:07:20.437769
 10 2016-09-27 14:07:20.437796
100 2016-09-27 14:07:23.293661
```